# Filtering Arango query results to report an array intersection in AQL

Tags: json, filter, arangodb

I am experimenting with ArangoDB as a replacement for Postgres which I am currently using.  In Postgres I have a table, `zuffs` containing rows bearing the following form

```
 hash       passes     visits   

 123        {1,2,4}   {2,3,4,5}
```

where both `passes` and `visits` are `int[]`.  In order to establish the intersection of `passes` and visits` I would write

```
SELECT ARRAY
(
 SELECT UNNEST(a1) INTERSECT SELECT UNNEST(a2))
 FROM (SELECT passes AS a1,visits as a2 FROM zuffs where hash = 1) q;
```

which Postgres obligingly executes to return the result `{2,4}`.

Now suppose I have the collection `zuffs` in ArangoDB with the following `documents`

{"hash":45,"passes":[1,2,3],"visits":[3,11,17]}

{"hash":76,"passes":[11,2],"visits":[3,4,17]}

{"hash":13,"passes":[11,21],"visits":[13,44,27]}

{"hash":7,"passes":[2],"visits":[4,67]}

It is not clear to me how I would do the following

1. Establish the, intersection, **I1** of `passes` and `visits` for the document bearing the `hash` 45.
2. Take that result and return the hashes for other documents in the same collection that have a non-empty intersection with the the intersection **I2** obtained above.

While there is much I like about ArangoDB I find it unfortunate that it has its own query language instead of just using the required superset of SQL. In this instance I have figured out that I will somehow have to use `FOR IN` along with `FILTER` but it is not at all clear to me how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a SQL expert, I also fought against the syntax differences of AQL.  However, it really did not end up being that hard to understand, which made "learning" just a function of time and use.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but here's a quick/dirty example:

1. Find the document you want to match, and get it's intersection product
2. For each document `z` in `zuffs`, calculate the intersection and look for matches
3. Return the `hash` of matching documents

```
LET match = (
    FOR z IN zuffs
        FILTER z.hash == 45
        FOR i IN INTERSECTION(z.passes, z.visits)
            RETURN i
)
FOR z IN zuffs
    LET i = INTERSECTION(z.passes, z.visits)
    FOR m IN match
        FILTER m IN i
            RETURN z.hash
```

Returns:

```
[
  45
]
```

Given your example data set, you will only get back one document with meeting the requirements (45).  Adding more documents or modifying one of the other documents to have a common intersection will provide more interesting results.

Things to keep in mind:

1. Moving from SQL to AQL makes you shift your thinking from "sets" (of rows) to "loops" (over things).
2. Keep track of the return (or native) types (array vs object/string/etc.), and treat each piece of data accordingly (note the `FOR i IN INTERSECTION...` in the `match`).
3. Use the `Explain` and `Profile` buttons (or functions) to see how your query is performing. Think of other ways the result can be accomplished, and try to make it faster!

For instance:

```
LET match = FIRST(
    FOR z IN zuffs
        FILTER z.hash == 45
        RETURN INTERSECTION(z.passes, z.visits)
)
FOR z IN zuffs
    FILTER LENGTH( INTERSECTION(match, INTERSECTION(z.passes, z.visits)) ) > 0
        RETURN z.hash
```

The `match` sections of both examples return the same result (an array with a single value of `3`), but they do it in different ways.  And instead of doing a `FOR m IN match...`, I could have used native array functions with a filter.  In reality the first example is much quicker than the second, and the reason is evident in the "explain" plan.

I found it ***immensely*** helpful become familiar with the [high level](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations.html) and [function](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions.html) documentation.  Those two places will have almost everything you need to succeed with AQL (aside from "big picture" stuff like query tuning, indexing, etc.).